# Counting number of character occurrences per line

Tags: bash, perl, find-occurrences

I have a file that looks like this: ( Note : A*, B*, C* are placeholders). The file is delimited by `;`

```
AAAA;BBBB;CCCCCCCC;DD;EEEEEEEE;FF;
AAA1;BBBBB;CCCC;DD;EEEEEEEE;FFFFF;
AAA3;BB;CCCC;DDDDDDDDD;EEEEEEE;FF;
```

I m trying to write a small script that counts the number of occurrences of the delimiter `;` and if it is lesser or greater than 5, output said line to a text file.

```
delim=";"

while read line
do  
    n_of_occ=$(grep -o "$delim" <<< "$line" | wc -l)

    if [[ $n_of_occ < 5 ]] || [[ $n_of_occ > 5 ]]
    then
        echo $line >> outfile
    fi
done
```

For some reason, this doesn't seem to work and my output is garbled. Could someone assist or provide a different way to tackle this? Perhaps with Perl instead of bash?

Comment: You should try to supply a properly representative set of data. Every line of your sample has six semicolons `;` which, according to your rules, means they should all be printed. Once you have said *"The file is delimited by `;`"* there's little point in giving an example unless it tests the criteria and is accompanied by your corresponding required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately every line in your sample data has six semicolons, which means they should all be printed. However, here is a one-line Perl solution

```
$ perl -ne'print if tr/;// != 5' aaa.csv
AAAA;BBBB;CCCCCCCC;DD;EEEEEEEE;FF;
AAA1;BBBBB;CCCC;DD;EEEEEEEE;FFFFF;
AAA3;BB;CCCC;DDDDDDDDD;EEEEEEE;FF;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is ridiculous easy with `awk`:

`awk -F\; 'NF!=6' file > outfile`

Answer (score 1):

I would take this one-liner:

```
awk '{x=$0}gsub(";","",x)!=5' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if tr/;// != 5' input_file > output_file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- the `tr` operator returns the number of matches

Answer (score 1):

With sed you can do this:

```
sed '/^\([^;]*;\)\{5\}$/d' file > outfile
```

It deletes the lines with exactly 5 commas (`;`) and sends the output to *outfile*.

---

Or if you want your own code to work, then make the following changes:

1. replace `done` with `done <file`
2. replace `[[` with `((` and `]]` with `))` i.e use `((...))` instead of `[[...]]`